# Вывод модуля time на кириллице

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть модуль, который выводит дату модификации файла и записывает его в файл.
Хоть и определена локаль, вывода на кириллице нету

```
import os.path, time, locale


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Russian_Russia.1251')

file = '\path\my_file.txt'
file_date_mod = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))


f = open('last_date.txt', 'w')
for i in file_date_mod:
    f.write(i)

print(file_date_mod)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.ctime):

> Locale information is not used by ctime().

Перевод:

> `ctime()` не использует информацию о локали.

Можно поступить следующим образом:

```
format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S" # строка для нужного форматирования
print (strftime(format, time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file))))
```

[Справка по strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно заметили `time.ctime()` не обращает внимание на locale.
Вот еще один способ:

```
import os.path, time, locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Russian_Russia.1251')

file = 'sample.txt'
file_date_mod = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%a, %d %b, %H:%M:%S")

f = open('last_date.txt', 'w')
for i in file_date_mod:
    f.write(i)

print(file_date_mod)
```

output:

```
Вт, 06 ноя, 12:38:05
```

Comment: strawdog, Ваш способ, к сожалению, выводит все на англише.

Comment: @Vadin я добавил в ответ полный код. Вы, случаем, не забыли локаль прописать?

Comment: Спасибо @strawdog